# ASP.NET Core 2.2 How to override UserManager.CreateAsync to remove unique Username requirement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to override my UserManager.CreateAsync to remove the requirement of a unique Username. How can I do that?

So far this is what I have

```
public class CustomUserManager : UserManager<User>
{
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    public CustomUserManager(IUserStore<User> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
    IPasswordHasher<User> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<User>> userValidators,
    IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<User>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
    IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<User>> logger) : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(User user, string Password)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        user.TenantId = this.TenantId; 
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        }
        var result = dbContext.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == user.UserName && u.TenantId == user.TenantId);
        if (result == true)
        {
            return IdentityResult.Failed();
        }
        return await base.CreateAsync(user, Password);
    }
}
```

I can't force create the user due to me using base.CreateAsync. How can I overwrite what CreateAsync is doing?

I am stuck with this.

Comment: you want a username can be registered multiple times? what requirements guide here? if so, which account to login with same username?

Comment: There will be a TenantId in the User table that separates the Usernames.

Comment: You have to create your own user store and custom user object.  That way you write your own logic for the whole thing.  It will require more work.  Also have you tried NOT calling base.CreateAsync and writing your own logic?

Comment: perhaps differnet db or are you going to required they sepcify a TenantId? seems like perhaps your better off passing in TenantId, would be interesting in how you vision this to work. the containt is enforce on the DB, so you would need to remove it there and add a new one to include username and TenantId, then the createUser may be handled for you, you would need to verify.

Comment: I already have a custom User Object. The issue is that usermanager.createasync is stopping my user from being created. It keeps saying that there is a duplicate username. That means that the usermanager.createasync code is stopping me from creating my user. I have already removed the constraints on the db.

Comment: It's dummy algorithm but when you create user, you can map TenantId to Username so TenantId and Username columns will have same value.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Dummy algorithm? I dont want TenantId and Username to have the same value. I want to be able to have multiple similar usernames but with different tenant ids

Comment: how would you login in later with duplicated username? is TenantId a kind of `role`?

Comment: Yes, I will have an option to choose a Tenant and login from there. I am unsure of how I can further continue.

Comment: so use `Role` table instead. far more flexibility than `Tenant`.

Comment: otherwise, combine `username & tenantId` together in one as a real usernmae, like `username@tenentid`, save to column `UserName`, you can have another column to save first part. so all resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set dbContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false; see if it's working.